# In Yii, why use CActiveDataProvider instead of Post::model()->findAll()?

Tags: php, yii, yii-cmodel

I see `CActiveDataProvider` used in the controller `actionIndex()` function.

Is there any difference between using this instead of simply `Post::model()->findAll()`?

Comment: There's a documentation you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CActiveDataProvider` is a wrapper for `CActiveRecord` with extended capabilities of `sorting`, `pagination` and `filtering`. Typically `CActiveDataProvider` is being used in conjunction with `zii` widgets like `CListView` or `CGridView` which are utilizing its sort and search capabilities. So if you want to display data in terms of list or table with (optional) sorting/filtering/pagination - most convenient way of doing it in Yii is using described zii widgets or their extensions.

If you just need to fetch data and use it in any other way, but without smart rendering mechanisms provided by `CListView` or `CGridView` - use `CActiveRecord`, because it doesn't perform anything else except of fetching of data.

[reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25820-cactivedataprovider-vs-model-findall/page__view__findpost__p__124143)